# Oxid - Get product categories based on article id

Tags: oxid

I have an product that is assigned to more than 1 category.

I am interested how can i select all the categories that the product is assigned to based on productID.

something like get Article Categories (id Article)

Comment: `productID` is no official oxid-term. Do you mean the `OXID`?

Comment: oh, and that's why you hit downvote?

Comment: Thats a good and eligible question! The downvoting was not neccessary. Corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to get category ID's by using [oxArticle::getCategoryIds()](http://docu.oxid-esales.com/CE/sourcecodedocumentation/4.8.7/classox_article.html#a5104d395fcd1c48010f927987d006426), but you have to have article object loaded like:

```
$oArticle = oxNew('oxarticle');
$oArticle->load('id');
$aCategories = $oArticle->getCategoryIds();
```

If you need objects just foreach to load them.